# D3 zoom is constantly zooming down and right of SVG, how do I fix this?

Tags: javascript, css, d3.js, svg

I have a geographical map which I am trying to add zoom functionality to using D3. I am able to zoom but it seems like whenever I do it is constantly zooming down and to the right of where my cursor is. How can I make it so it zooms to the location of the cursor?

Below is a plunk of all my code. The zoom function is in "main.js". It's used in the "map" variable and is created right after that.

```
 //create a new svg element with the above dimensions
var map = d3.select("body")
            .append("svg")
            .attr("width", width)
            .attr("height", height)
            .call(d3.zoom()
                .scaleExtent([1/2, 4])
                .on("zoom", zoomed));

//zoom function used above                
function zoomed() {
  map.attr("transform", d3.event.transform);
}
```

http://plnkr.co/edit/0S1OJr?p=preview

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You should transform a `<group>` element, not the SVG:

```
var svg = d3.select("body")
    .append("svg")
    .attr("width", width)
    .attr("height", height);

//creating a group element named 'map':
var map = svg.append("g").call(d3.zoom()
    .scaleExtent([1 / 2, 4])
    .on("zoom", zoomed));

function zoomed() {
    map.attr("transform", d3.event.transform);
    //applying the transform to 'map'
}
```

Here is the updated plunker: http://plnkr.co/edit/B0o0tULpve1rbpyRgFpz?p=preview

Comment: Thanks a lot! It seems like I'll have to look into how to properly structure things in D3 more.

Comment: @Dan actually this has more to do with SVG than with D3: what can happen if you apply the transform to the whole SVG? Do you see?

Comment: I'm not sure I understand what you mean. Wouldn't that be what I was doing before? I'm not very knowledgeable about this stuff either so I'm probably just confused haha.

Comment: Exactly: you were translating the whole SVG, which makes little sense. You have to translate an element inside that SVG. So, the issue here is knowing more about SVG, not about D3. That's my point.

Comment: Ok I understand. Thanks for the advice!